# Recreate user profiles after reinstalling Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, user-profiles, reinstall

I have a Windows 7 Home Pro system with a SSD boot drive and conventional HDD for user accounts. I created a junction to make `C:\Users` point to `D:\Users` and all was well.

Now the SSD got corrupted and I needed to reinstall Windows. That went fine but all my user accounts vanished. No problem, just recreate them and re-junction `D:\Users` into place.

the problem is, no one can log in. One account gets a GPO error and immediately logs out, all the rest just get logged into temporary profiles.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to assign ACLs for the new users (different User Ids) to the respective home folders. If you turn off simple file sharing and look into the security tab of a home folders properties, you will notice that instead of usernames there are ACLs for long numbers. This is because the old user ids are no longer valid. Just add Full Control rights for your users to their folders.

Answer (score 0):

Log in as Administrator.
Go to c:\users and give permissions to "everyone" for each of the old profile folders.
Open the registry. Back it up.
Go to HKLM\Software\Microfost\Windows NT\Current Version\ProfileList
Locate one of the temporary profiles.
Change the value for "ProfileImagePath" to point to the old profile folder.
Repeat for the rest of the temporary profiles. 
Restart.
Login.